# How to call custom directive on form submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive which works when I once change input value but when I submit form without changing input field value directive does not display error message.

**html code:**

```
    <form name="myform" role="form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="firstName">First name :</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
             <input name='firstName' class="form-control" type='text' required ng-model='name' string>
</div>
        </div>
 <div class="form-group">

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>

    </form>
```

**directive :**

```
 validationModule.directive('string', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',

        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
            function validationError(value) {

                if (value.length < 1) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('required', false);
                    //showPopOver(element, "Required field");
                    errorValidation(element, "Required field");
               //     $(element).popover('show');
                }
                if (/[a-zA-Z]/.test(value)) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('invalid', true);
                    // $(element).popover('destroy');
                    successValidation(element);
                }
                if (/[0-9]/.test(value)) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('invalid', false)
                    errorValidation(element, "number not allowed");
                    // showPopOver(element, "number not allowed");
                 //   $(element).popover('show');
                }

                return value;
            }
            ctrl.$parsers.push(validationError);
        }
    };
});
```

**How can I call directive to perform validation on submit event ?**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of angular you are using, but since 1.3 validators are not hacked into parsers. See $validators in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController
Also using such generic names for directives is discouraged due to possible name collisions. Use some prefix eg myString